# importing frameworks in swift does not work Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: swift, core-location

can someone help me with below screenshot. I have imported the corelocation framewok in build phases-> link binary with libraries. what else should i be doing? i have also tried self.locationManager and still i have the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

now it seems to be working withou tme having to do any settings change. But i removed also removed one method locationManager.locationServicesEnabled which was a depricated method.